# jquery/javascript how to get rid of blank spaces (replace() not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, substring, whitespace

Hi all,

I have a string coming from my database:

```
var theString = "LNDSH   - LONDON SHOPS";
```

I need to get two variables out of it.

One with the code before the -, and the other one with the sentence after the -.

To do so I do:

```
var sentence = $.trim(theString.substring((theString.indexOf('-')+1),theString.length)); 
var code = $.trim(theString.substring(0, theString.indexOf('-')));
```

var sentence is ok, but I cannot get rid of the spaces before the - in the code variable.

I really need to get rid of those spaces.

Please note that in var sentence I'm doing +1 because it is always one space in between the sentence and the -.

But in the case of the code: I don't know the length of the code and I don't know how many spaces will be before the -

I've tried:

```
code.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

But this does not show a thing in my page (no javascript errors either).

I'm using jquery-1.5.1.min and jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A bit off topic, but why are you using such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: _"no javascript errors either"_ - Are you sure? JS doesn't have a `.replaceAll()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
variable.replace(/\s/g,'');
```

Edit: The above **will not** seperate your strings, it will only remove the white spaces.

To seperate the strings you can do this:

```
var seperate = theString.split("-", 2);
var LNDSH = seperate[0];
var LONDON_SHOPS = seperate[1];
```

Comment: Why was there downvotes? +1 good answer. $replaceAll is for elements afaik.

Comment: Might be worth using `split("-", 2)` to ensure only two strings are returned.

Comment: @Jon time for more coffee!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You may use `split` with regular expression:

```
var values = "LNDSH   - LONDON SHOPS".split(/\s*-\s*/);

console.log(values[0]);  // "LNDSH"
console.log(values[1]);  // "LONDON SHOPS"
```

Comment: Might be worth using `split(/\s*-\s*/, 2)` to ensure only two strings are returned.

Comment: @Jon Could do. It depends on the requirements.

Comment: @Jon - if the other code only uses the first two array items it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @VisioN the OP specifies in their code that sentence should contain from the first instance of "-" to the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
var theString = "LNDSH   - LONDON SHOPS";

var vett = theString.split("-");
var a = vett[0].trim();
var b = vett[1].trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = theString.split("-");
 alert(test[0].trim());
 alert(test[1].trim());
```

Comment: Note that JS's `.trim()` won't work in IE<=8. (But OP is using jQuery, so can use `$.trim()`.)